# Java web application with wildfly can't create Entity classes from database

Tags: java, xml, database, maven, wildfly

The issue when I'm trying to create entity classes:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeItK.png)

(Just got wildfly's example db connection, so I can't choose my db connection)
Versions:

- Wildfly 26.1.2
- Java mysql connector 8.0.23
- Java EE 7 Web
- Jdk 17
- Netbeans 15
- Xampp 7.4.29
- Windows 10 :(

At Services -> Databases, the db connection test works with the above version of mysql connector

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>mavenproject1</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.23</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I tried with more versions, but nothing works.

Comment: What kind of error are you seeing? You're also compiling to Java 1.7 which I wouldn't suggest.

Comment: Dear James R. Perkins! I edited the question, you can see the error in a png. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: This looks like an IDE issue. I wouldn't think your POM has anything to do with it, but I haven't used NetBeans in a very long time ;)

Comment: I reinstalled netbeans, and I'm a student, my classmates have the same issue

Comment: A guess would be you need to setup the database connection in NetBeans. I don't know how that works though.

Comment: I maked the db connection, tested it and its working.

Comment: Okay, I managed to do something: I deployed the project, then manually created a datasource (with db connection) on the wildfly page. Which found the mysql connector through the deployed project. This is how it works now, it brings out and I can generate the classes. However, this is quite lengthy work. Any idea how to fix it so I can generate the classes automatically?